# I want to open pop up after 60 seconds using jquery. on close it will not open in next 20 minutes or page refresh after 20 minutes reopen it

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my popup code . i want to show it after 1 minutes user enter site. if user close it will not open in next 20 minutes or page refresh after 20 minutes reopen it. i want to do it with jquery.

```
<div class="subs-popup" style="display:none;">
<div id="consult">
<div class="closepopup">x</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific in what you are struggling with? Is it opening the popup in general? Is is the timer stuff? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a function to launch modal [ TriggerModal(); ] then use this code

```
    <script>

//for open modal after 1sec
setTimeout(function(){
$('.subs-popup').TriggerModal('show');
},1000);

//for close popup
$(".closepopup").click(function(){

//immediately it close modal
$('.subs-popup').hide();

//open modal after 20sec
setTimeout(function(){
$('.subs-popup').TriggerModal('show');
},20000);

});

//if page reloaded
function loaded()
{
    $('.subs-popup').removeClass('subs-popup').addClass("newDummy");
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.newDummy').addClass('subs-popup');
    },19000);
}
window.onload = loaded;

</script>
```

Comment: popup is showing but if any one refresh the page then it open in 1sec. i want if any one close it once then it will open after next 20 min